# Restrict access to screen transitions for unauthorized user

Tags: moqui

I want to restrict access to screen transitions for unauthorized user.

This is what I did:

1) I created UserGroups and added certain users to those user groups.
2) I also created certain ArtifactGroups.
3) Associated UserGroups with ArtifactGroups by 'ArtifactAuthz' entity.
4) Added certain artifacts to ArtifactGroups using ArtifactGroupMember.

I am able to restrict/allow access of screen artifacts but not able to restrict access to screen transitions.

Prepared data to add screen transition artifact into artifact group.

```
<moqui.security.ArtifactGroupMember artifactGroupId="CONFIG_ADMIN" artifactName="/tutorial/getTutorials" artifactTypeEnumId="AT_XML_SCREEN_TRANS" inheritAuthz="Y"/>
```

I doubt, I am not using proper artifactName. I also tried to find sample data for screen transitions but couldn't find any.
Please provide sample data to add screen transitions into artifact groups.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something used very often, and while it was part of the original design I've always found better ways to handle a given need. That said, it is supported. In older versions of Moqui the format is:

"${parentScreen.location}.transition_${name}"

Since that is cumbersome I changed it in commit #ed0fd6e to be more like the format used for other things elsewhere:

"${parentScreen.location}/${name}"

If you pull now from the GitHub moqui/moqui repository that is what you'd use.

Comment: Thank you David for your support. I am using master branch of moqui framework and In my case, '${parentScreen.location}.transition_${name}' working fine. I think your commit #ed0fd6e is not merged in master branch yet.